# How to take user input for prediction scikitlearn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, streamlit

I'm trying to make a web app with Streamlit and would like to take user input for predicting the next values using polynomial regression with scikitlearn.

I use this for user input with streamlit

```
user_input = st.number_input("input number")
```

Then this to predict from a tutorial I found

```
pol.predict(poly.fit_transform(user_input))
```

That does not work and I get this error:

```
ValueError: Expected 2D array, got scalar array instead:
array=0.0.
Reshape your data either using array.reshape(-1, 1) if your data has a single feature or array.reshape(1, -1) if it contains a single sample
```

.

Then I tried the following from a tutorial online:

```
model = numpy.poly1d(numpy.polyfit(X,y,3))
number = model(user_input)
print(case)
```

I receive this error:

```
TypeError: ufunc add cannot use operands with types dtype('<M8[ns]') and dtype('float64')
```

If this is an issue with date time data, I converted it previously. As for the other error, I reshaped the data previously as well when I was defining X and y.

Do you know how to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most scikit-learn functions work with numpy array data types, so your input needs to be of type numpy array. The raw input that you get using `st.number_input` is likely a float, so you need to store it in a numpy array like:

```
user_input = np.array(user_input).reshape(-1,1)
```

assuming the model expects the input feature vector X to have one feature.

Also, I don't know why you're using `st.number_input` instead of the far more general `input()` command, and then casting the input. This will probably be a bit more robust and won't give you a datatype like `dtype('<M8[ns]')`

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment! I was wondering why my question was downvoted-is there a way that I could improve?

Comment: Your question was likely downvoted because it doesn't seem like you put much effort into solving the problem. For instance, my answer is basically just a rephrasing of the error message you received. If you're new to Python, it can be a bit daunting to look into these error messages but just doing a simple search of the error will normally give you similar issues other people have faced.

Comment: If this question is answered can you accept the answer and close the question to keep SO clean?